# Mongo custom serializer fails when running several test fixtures in a row

Tags: mongodb, nunit

I am using Nunit for unit testing a project that uses MongoDb. I need a custom serializer to serialize objects from my own namespaces. I have encapsulated this registration within a static function. I need to use this function in the SetUp of my tests. If I run my test fixtures one by one it works. However if I try to run them all, I run into this exception:
`MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException : There is already a serializer registered for type Object.`

I use MongoDb v5.0 with driver v2.22 and NUnit v2.6.4

Here's some edited code:

```
public static class MongoSerializerHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Registers all types whose namespace starts with "MyNameSpace"
    /// </summary>
    public static void RegisterCustomTypesForSerializer()
    {
     
     var objectSerializer = new ObjectSerializer(type =>
     {
       var isTypePartOfNameSpace = type.FullName.StartsWith("MyNameSpace");
       return ObjectSerializer.DefaultAllowedTypes(type) || isTypePartOfNameSpace;
     });

     BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(objectSerializer);
    }
}
```

```
[TestFixture]
public class OneTestFixture
{
  [TestFixtureSetUp]
  public void SetUp()
  {
    MongoSerializerHelper.RegisterCustomTypesForSerializer();
  }
  
  //tests after that
}
```

It could seem that the issue is that my serializer is registered several times but that is not the case: if I run several test fixtures in the same run, starting with one that *doesn't* register a serializer, the second test fixture will fail with the same error on the first try of the registration.
In no other part of the project is a serializer registered. Moreover if this was the case you'd see the actual type in the error message instead of `Object`.
I have looked up the error message online but I didn't find any reference to this error occurring with `Object`.